# Read values from text file into 2D numpy array using index values from the text file

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I need to read a text file that contains comma-delimited values into a 2D numpy array. The first 2 values on each line contain the index values for the numpy array and the third values contains the value to be stored in the array. As a catch, the index values are 1-based and need to be converted to the 0-based index values used by numpy. I've reviewed documentation and examples using genfromtxt and loadtxt but it's still not clear to me how to go about it. I've also tried the following code with no success:

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

for line in infile:
    fields = line.split() #split fields inti list
    rindex = int(fields[0]) - 1
    cindex = int(fields[1]) - 1
    a[rindex,cindex] = float(fields[2])
```

Here is an example of the input file:

```
1,1,10.1
1,2,11.2
1,3,12.3
2,3,13.4
2,2,14.5
2,3,15.6
```

And here is my desired output array. Ideally I'd like it to work on any array size without having to predefine the size of the array.

```
10.1 11.2 12.3
13.4 14.5 15.6
```

Comment: `data = np.genfromtxt('path_to_file',converters = {0: lambda x: int(x) - 1, 1: lambda x: int(x) - 1}, delimiter = ",").reshape(2,3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it.  `numpy.genfromtxt()` is used to read the data into a structured array with three fields.  The row and column indices are pulled out of the structured array and used to figure out the shape of the desired array, and to assign the values to the new array using numpy's "fancy" indexing:

```
In [46]: !cat test_data.csv
1,1,10.1
1,2,11.2
1,3,12.3
2,3,13.4
2,2,14.5
2,3,15.6

In [47]: data = np.genfromtxt('test_data.csv', dtype=None, delimiter=',', names=['i', 'j', 'value'])

In [48]: data
Out[48]: 
array([(1, 1, 10.1), (1, 2, 11.2), (1, 3, 12.3), (2, 3, 13.4),
       (2, 2, 14.5), (2, 3, 15.6)], 
      dtype=[('i', '<i8'), ('j', '<i8'), ('value', '<f8')])

In [49]: rows = data['i']

In [50]: cols = data['j']

In [51]: nrows = rows.max()

In [52]: ncols = cols.max()

In [53]: a = np.zeros((nrows, ncols))

In [54]: a[rows-1, cols-1] = data['value']

In [55]: a
Out[55]: 
array([[ 10.1,  11.2,  12.3],
       [  0. ,  14.5,  15.6]])
```